# Way to clear Bulletin for a processor

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

For quick testing and development, it would really be helpful to have a way to clear the Bulletin from processor's top right corner. Once I see the error and I fix it, I would like to clear it before restarting.

If it is possible with the current version, please guide.

Comment: Not a very usefull use case for this possible function

Comment: Definitely not a blocker feature for building pipelines. But it would be very convenient for testing. Let's say I ran some pipeline and it threw Warn level Bulletin and after I make fixes, I have to currently hover again and check the time for bulletin to see if that's a new error or old one only.

Comment: There is no way to do this currently.

Comment: You can follow this issue on Jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2056

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments there is currently no way to do this. However, you can probably achieve your goal of seeing whether your error is resolved in the following way:

0. Change your processors config, hopefully fixing the problem
1. Check the last timestamp of the error bulletin
2. Start the processor
3. Wait a few seconds and check if the error bulletin still has the old timestamp

This has helped me greatly in speeding up development.

---

Extra trick:

If you are really in a place where you can safely play around, and don't want to focus, you can also copy the processor and re-direct the queues to/from there. It is more work, but will get you a clean bulletin.

I mostly used this trick if I had to demo something and I cannot afford to wait 5 minutes for the red square to disappear.